# program to verify a number by two requirements

Tags: c++, windows, verify

I'm trying to make a program that verifies if a number meets two requirements:

1. the number has 4 digits
2. not all the digits are the same

I've been made it, and it looks good, but the code fails in a specific case.

When the user enters a number with all of the digits equal, like `1111`, the first time the program will say that this number isn't correct and will ask for a new number, but if the user enters another invalid number with all digits equal, like `2222`, the verification fails and accepts this new number as a valid number.

I don't know what the problem could be, can someone help?

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int n; // number 
    cout << "enter a 4-digit number with at least one different digit number: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    int m = 0, o = 0, u = n, z = 0; // variables
    int counter, counter1, counter2 = 5; //counters 
    int x[4], y[4]; // vectors 
    
    //--------------------------- verification -------------------------------------
    while(counter != 4 && counter2 > 3){ 
        // ======= number size verification =======
        while (u > 0){
            u = u/10;
            counter = counter + 1; // number digit counter
        }
        
        if(counter != 4){ // if the number has less than 4 digits
            cout << "the number has less than 4 digits, enter a valid number: ";
            cin >> n;
            
            u = n;
        }
        // =================================================
        
        // ========= check repetead numbers ================
        if(counter == 4){ // if the number has 4 digits
            u = n;
            z = n;
            for(int i = 3; i >= 0; i--){ // convert the number into two vectors
                u = u % 10;
                x[i] = u;
                y[i] = u;
                z = z / 10;
                u = z;
            }
            
            counter2 = 0; // repetition counter 2 (reset counter value)
            
            // traversal of the vector in search of repeated numbers
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
              counter1 = 0; // repetition counter 1 (reset counter value) 
                m = x[j];
                for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
                  o = y[k];
                    if(m == o){ 
                        counter1 = counter1 + 1; // if there are repeated numbers counter increases
                        y[k] = 0; // delete that vector position
                    }
                }
                
                if(counter1 == 1 || counter1 == 0){ // if only found the repetition of the same box
                  counter1 = 0; // reset counter1
                }else{
                  counter2 = counter2 + counter1; // if not, its value is assigned to counter2
                }
            }
            

        }
        
        if(counter2 == 4){ // if the number has all its digits the same
            n = 0;
            cout << "the number has all its digits the same, enter a valid number: ";
            cin >> n;
        }
        
    }
    
    cout << "valid number";
    
    return 0;
}
```

image of the failure:

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that all numbers with four digits are between 1000 and 9999? Isn't easier to simply compare if the number is between 1000 and 9999, instead of all this overengineered, fragile, error-prone complexity? And if you think about it a little bit more, how to check if not all numbers are the same can also be done in a much, much simpler way than all of this cumbersome logic. The entire logic should be more than four or five lines of code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the last line of you comment , i think you mean "the entire logic should not be more than four or five lines of code".

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes bro i know, at the moment i thought that was a good way to solve it but really was terrible , i forgot went to the simple way .

Comment: This is just a small example of what you can expect from any one of a number of useless coding puzzle web sites, that offer useless coding puzzles on the promise that solving them will turn anyone into an instant C++ uberhacker. Anyone can simply ask themselves: what, specific, C++ knowledge was gained from this coding puzzle? Answer: none at all.

Comment: `int counter, counter1` are not initialized, so following ` while(counter != 4` leads to UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if your number is 4 digits you can simply compare it:

```
if( n < 1000 or n > 9999 ) // not 4 digits number
```

To check if all digits are the same, just check if it is divisible by 1111 (thanks to @SamVarshavchik )

```
if( n % 1111 == 0 ) // all digits are the same
```

Comment: Oh, come on, there's no need to involve silly string conversions and comparisons. Really, have we all forgot elementary school math? What's wrong with dividing the number by 1111, and checking if the remainder is 0?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you are right, mia culpa Sometimes simple solutions do not come to your mind :) I just started to think how to implement whole check by input that number as string.

Comment: Finally -- someone who's spelling, grammar, and punctuation is just as lousy as mine's... Pleased to meet you. (P.S. You meant "All digits are not the same")

Comment: @Slava thank you so muuuuuuch, i dont know why didnt think in that option , im stupid xd